# How to return the previous 7 days in Teradata

Tags: teradata

```
SELECT 
DD.DATE_DATE AS Claim_Rcv_Date 
from claim claim INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DD 
ON DD.DATE_DIM_CK = CLAIM.CLAIM_RCVD_DATE_DIM_CK 
WHERE ???
```

How would I limit to the previous 7 days? Using the DD.DATE_DATE AS Claim_Rcv_Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the date column is actually stored as a proper date type, you can use:

```
WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do so it does not return any data. DO you have any idea why? I even changed the 7 to 14

Comment: That might be something with your data. To see, try hard coding the dates: `WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN '2020-11-09' and '2020-11-16'`

Comment: There is data when I hard code the dates. I dont knw why the logic is not working

Comment: You are the man! It worked just had some mistake! Thanks

Comment: If it's a DATE you can simply use `current_date -7` instead